Unity - Play core library conflict (Android abb build error) - Include this empty monolithic Play Core library as a local maven repository, how to?
I’m using Unity 2022.3.39 and updated to the latest version of google play asset delivery from here https://developers.google.com/unity/packages#google_play
Before updating I had an older version of the asset delivery plugin and building the app worked. Now I am getting the error that two libraries are conflicting. I am suspecting the cause is this:
https://github.com/google/play-unity-plugins/blob/master/README.md#play-core-conflicts

Play Core library conflicts
When building an Android App Bundle with Unity's build system (e.g. "File > Build and Run"), Unity may include the monolithic Play Core library in a way that causes conflicts with the new Play libraries included by Google Play Plugins for Unity.


To resolve these conflicts, follow the steps below:


Enable "Custom Main Gradle Template" in "Android Player > Publishing Settings"
Enable "Patch mainTemplate.gradle" in "Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Settings"
Include this empty monolithic Play Core library as a local maven repository
These steps will allow EDM4U to update the mainTemplate.gradle to include the empty monolithic Play Core library as a gradle dependency. This will override the version of the Play Core library included by Unity and resolve the duplicate class errors and manifest merger failures.

Can anyone please tell, in stupid-proof steps, me how to implement step 3, namely "Include this empty monolithic Play Core library as a local maven repository" in Unity?
I tried everything except for praying.
LE: error I'm getting
D:\Working Area\Project001\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\launcher\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:26:17-38 Error:
Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.versionCode@value value=(20201) from [com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.2.1] AndroidManifest.xml:26:17-38
is also present at [com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3] AndroidManifest.xml:38:17-38 value=(11003).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.
